# Why my proof is wrong (space of linear maps is complete)?

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

Am trying to prove if $B$ is a space of all linear maps from $X$ to $ \Omega $ s.t. $\|T\| < \infty$, where $\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|_\Omega : \|x\|_X \leq 1\}$, such that $\Omega$ is complete, then $B$ is complete.

SO far I tried the following sketch:-

let $\sum_n T_n$ s.t. $\sum_n \|T_n\| < \infty $ as $n \to \infty$

\begin{align}
\implies & \exists Tx \in \text{s.t. } \|Tx - \sum_nT_nx\| < \varepsilon \text{ (since } \Omega \text{ is complete)} \\[8pt]
\implies & \sum_nT_nx -\varepsilon < T_n < \sum_n T_nx + \varepsilon, \text{ as } n \to \infty, \forall x \in X \text{ s.t. } \|x\| \leq 1 \\[8pt]
\implies & \|T_x\| < \infty \\[8pt]
\implies & T \in B(X,\Omega) \\[8pt]
\implies & \sum_nT_n \text{ s.t. } T_n \in B(X,\Omega)
\end{align}
and  $\sum_n \|T_n\| < \infty  \implies \exists T \in B(X,\Omega) \text{ s.t. } \|T-\sum_nT_n\| < \varepsilon$ as $n \to \infty \implies B(X,\Omega)$ is complete.

Comment: Why you take a series of $T_n$? You need to show that if $(T_n)_n\in B$ is cauchy sequence then there is $T\in B$ such that $T_n\to T$ in $\|\cdot\|$ norm.

Comment: @Irddo There is a theorem that says this: a normed real/complex vector space $(V,\lVert\bullet\rVert)$ is a Banach space if and only if for all sequences $x_n\in V$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \lVert x_k\rVert<\infty$ there exists $s\in V$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n x_k=s$.

Comment: BTW, your notation is painful. In the symbol $\sum_n ||T_n||$, the $n$ is a dummy index. You can't specify "$n\to\infty$". I guess you probably mean partial sums with $n$ terms, but don't use the same symbol for the index and for the number of terms. I would accept $\sum_k^n ||T_k||$ if you really want to abbreviate, or even $\sum^n ||T_k||$, but not $\sum_n ||T_n||$ when you are specifying $n\to\infty$.

Comment: yes i did try to use that theorem because i find it easier to prove that way.
@MPW, yes, I meant partial sums, sorry my ignorance,

but is the proof strategy technically correct otherwise (also X and $\Omega$ are normed linear spaces)?

Comment: Would someone please approve the pending edit? (I already did.) Someone working with this kind of math might benefit from learning MathJax coding. The code in the original post is really sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

The first arrow, you should denote the norm with $\|\cdot\|_\Omega$, maybe what you want to say is: for each fixed $x\in X$, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T_nx\|_\Omega \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T_n\|_{op}\|x\|_X < \infty$$
since $\Omega$ is complete, (by the lemma you mentioned) there exists an element in $\Omega$, denote as $Tx$ such that the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^k T_nx \rightarrow Tx$ under the norm in $\Omega$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

The second arrow, I think there is a typo between the inequality, should not be $T_n$. And more importantly, note that $\sum_{n=1}^k T_n x$ is an element in $\Omega$, and I assume your $\epsilon$ is an element in $\mathbb{R}$, you can not just subtract two elements in different vector spaces. You need to put $\|\cdot\|_\Omega$ around $\sum_{n=1}^k T_n x$.

After the first arrow, you just need to show that the $T$ defined by 
$$T(x) := \lim_k \sum_{n=1}^k T_n(x)$$is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $\Omega$.